# Null pointer exception: Result must not be null in Fragment class

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, calculator

I'm trying to implement a calculator in my multi-purpose app, but I've run into a small problem. I've implemented the calculator function in a Fragment class. Every time I click the Calculator fragment the whole app crashes.

Here's the code and got help with from a tutorial.

**Calculator Fragment**

```
    package com.khumomashapa.notes.fragments

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.khumomashapa.notes.R
import com.khumomashapa.notes.helper.OperationsHelper
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_calculator.*

class CalculatorFragment : Fragment() {

    var digit_on_screen = StringBuilder(12)
    var operation: Char = ' '
    var leftHandSide: Double = 0.0
    var rightHandSide: Double = 0.0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        result_id.text = "0"
        initializeButtons()

    }


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calculator, container, false)

    }

    private fun initializeButtons() {
        functionalButtons()
        operationalButtons()
        numericalButtons()
    }

    /**
     * This function initializes all of our numerical buttons from
     *  [0 - 9]
     */
    private fun numericalButtons() {

        one_btn.setOnClickListener {
            appendToDigitOnScreen("1")
        }

        two_btn.setOnClickListener {
            appendToDigitOnScreen("2")
        }

        three_btn.setOnClickListener {
            appendToDigitOnScreen("3")
        }

        four_btn.setOnClickListener {
            appendToDigitOnScreen("4")
        }

        five_btn.setOnClickListener {
            appendToDigitOnScreen("5")
        }

        six_btn.setOnClickListener {
            appendToDigitOnScreen("6")
        }

        seven_btn.setOnClickListener {
            appendToDigitOnScreen("7")
        }

        eight_btn.setOnClickListener {
            appendToDigitOnScreen("8")
        }

        nine_btn.setOnClickListener {
            appendToDigitOnScreen("9")
        }

        zero_btn.setOnClickListener {
            appendToDigitOnScreen("0")
        }

        dot_btn.setOnClickListener {
            appendToDigitOnScreen(".")
        }


    }

    /**
     *  Insert the button been clicked onto the screen so user can see
     *  inputs for the button clicked
     */
    private fun appendToDigitOnScreen(digit: String) {

        // Add each digit to our string builder
        digit_on_screen.append(digit)

        // display it on the screen of our mobile app
        result_id.text = digit_on_screen.toString()
    }

    /**
     *  Initialize the operation keys in our calculator like the
     *  addition key, subtraction key and the likes
     */
    private fun operationalButtons() {

        addition_btn.setOnClickListener {
            selectOperation('A')
        }

        subtract_btn.setOnClickListener {
            selectOperation('S')
        }

        divide_btn.setOnClickListener {
            selectOperation('D')
        }

        multipy_btn.setOnClickListener {
            selectOperation('M')
        }

    }

    /**
     * Function to assign operational sign to our math calculations
     */
    private fun selectOperation(c: Char) {

        operation = c
        leftHandSide = digit_on_screen.toString().toDouble()
        digit_on_screen.clear()
        result_id.text = "0"
    }

    /**
     * Handles functional operations in out application like
     * clear button, backspace button and the clear everything button
     */
    private fun functionalButtons() {

        clear_everything_btn.setOnClickListener {
            digit_on_screen.clear()
            result_id.text = "0"
        }

        clear_btn.setOnClickListener {

            if (digit_on_screen.length <= 0) {
                return@setOnClickListener
            } else {
                clearDigit()
            }
        }

        backspace_btn.setOnClickListener {
            if (digit_on_screen.length <= 0) {
                return@setOnClickListener
            } else {
                clearDigit()
            }
        }

        equal_btn.setOnClickListener {
            performMathOperation()
        }

    }


    /**
     *  This function performs our Math Operation which is then showed on the screen.
     */
    private fun performMathOperation() {

        rightHandSide = digit_on_screen.toString().toDouble()


        when (operation) {

            'A' -> {
                val sum = OperationsHelper.add(leftHandSide, rightHandSide)
                result_id.text = sum.toString()
                digit_on_screen.clear()
                digit_on_screen.append(sum)
            }
            'S' -> {
                val subtract = OperationsHelper.subtract(leftHandSide, rightHandSide)
                result_id.text = subtract.toString()
                digit_on_screen.clear()
                digit_on_screen.append(subtract)
            }
            'M' -> {
                val multiply = OperationsHelper.multiply(leftHandSide, rightHandSide)
                result_id.text = multiply.toString()
                digit_on_screen.clear()
                digit_on_screen.append(multiply)
            }
            'D' -> {
                val divide = OperationsHelper.divide(leftHandSide, rightHandSide)
                result_id.text = divide.toString()
                digit_on_screen.clear()
                digit_on_screen.append(divide)
            }

        }

    }

    /**
     *  This function remove the last digit on the screen.
     */
    private fun clearDigit() {

        val length = digit_on_screen.length

        digit_on_screen.deleteCharAt(length - 1)
        if (length <= 0) {
            result_id.text = "0"
        }else{
            result_id.text = digit_on_screen.toString()
        }


    }


}
```

**The Logcat**

```
    2021-03-28 11:25:35.688 25778-25778/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2021-03-28 11:25:35.689 25778-25778/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2021-03-28 11:25:35.697 25778-25778/? I/momashapa.note: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-03-28 11:25:35.716 25778-25778/? E/momashapa.note: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-03-28 11:25:35.724 25778-25778/? D/ActivityThread: setConscryptValidator
2021-03-28 11:25:35.724 25778-25778/? D/ActivityThread: setConscryptValidator - put
2021-03-28 11:25:36.122 25778-25778/com.khumomashapa.notes D/PhoneWindow: forceLight changed to true [] from com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.updateForceLightNavigationBar:4274 com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.updateColorViews:1547 com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.dispatchWindowAttributesChanged:3252 android.view.Window.setFlags:1153 com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.generateLayout:2474 
2021-03-28 11:25:36.123 25778-25778/com.khumomashapa.notes I/MultiWindowDecorSupport: [INFO] isPopOver = false
2021-03-28 11:25:36.123 25778-25778/com.khumomashapa.notes I/MultiWindowDecorSupport: updateCaptionType >> DecorView@ab7bf2e[], isFloating: false, isApplication: true, hasWindowDecorCaption: false, hasWindowControllerCallback: true
2021-03-28 11:25:36.123 25778-25778/com.khumomashapa.notes D/MultiWindowDecorSupport: setCaptionType = 0, DecorView = DecorView@ab7bf2e[]
2021-03-28 11:25:36.181 25778-25778/com.khumomashapa.notes W/momashapa.note: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-03-28 11:25:36.182 25778-25778/com.khumomashapa.notes W/momashapa.note: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-03-28 11:25:36.403 25778-25778/com.khumomashapa.notes I/ViewRootImpl@32ff46b[MainActivity]: setView = com.android.internal.policy.DecorView@ab7bf2e TM=true MM=false
2021-03-28 11:25:36.445 25778-25778/com.khumomashapa.notes I/ViewRootImpl@32ff46b[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2400) new=(0,0,1080,2400) req=(1080,2400)0 dur=15 res=0x7 s={true 507110252544} ch=true
2021-03-28 11:25:36.445 25778-27904/com.khumomashapa.notes D/OpenGLRenderer: createReliableSurface : 0x758376d580(0x7612206000)
2021-03-28 11:25:36.446 25778-27904/com.khumomashapa.notes I/AdrenoGLES: QUALCOMM build                   : eb230ec, I000594fe7d
    Build Date                       : 04/01/20
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.27.05.03
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.8.9.R1.10.00.00.558.065
    Remote Branch                    : NONE
    Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
2021-03-28 11:25:36.446 25778-27904/com.khumomashapa.notes I/AdrenoGLES: Build Config                     : S P 8.0.12 AArch64
2021-03-28 11:25:36.451 25778-27904/com.khumomashapa.notes I/AdrenoGLES: PFP: 0x016ee187, ME: 0x00000000
2021-03-28 11:25:36.481 25778-27904/com.khumomashapa.notes D/OpenGLRenderer: makeCurrent EglSurface : 0x0 -> 0x0
2021-03-28 11:25:36.485 25778-27904/com.khumomashapa.notes D/OpenGLRenderer: eglCreateWindowSurface : 0x757f3dce80
2021-03-28 11:25:36.522 25778-27904/com.khumomashapa.notes D/OpenGLRenderer: makeCurrent EglSurface : 0x0 -> 0x757f3dce80
2021-03-28 11:25:36.527 25778-27904/com.khumomashapa.notes W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
2021-03-28 11:25:36.625 25778-25778/com.khumomashapa.notes I/ViewRootImpl@32ff46b[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1
2021-03-28 11:25:36.626 25778-25778/com.khumomashapa.notes D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@ab7bf2e[MainActivity]
2021-03-28 11:25:36.626 25778-25778/com.khumomashapa.notes D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2021-03-28 11:25:36.633 25778-25778/com.khumomashapa.notes D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@ab7bf2e[MainActivity]
2021-03-28 11:25:36.633 25778-25778/com.khumomashapa.notes D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2021-03-28 11:25:36.633 25778-25778/com.khumomashapa.notes V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=com.khumomashapa.notes ic=null mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
2021-03-28 11:25:36.633 25778-25778/com.khumomashapa.notes D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
2021-03-28 11:25:36.633 25778-25778/com.khumomashapa.notes I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
2021-03-28 11:25:36.647 25778-25778/com.khumomashapa.notes I/ViewRootImpl@32ff46b[MainActivity]: MSG_RESIZED: frame=(0,0,1080,2400) ci=(0,91,0,126) vi=(0,91,0,126) or=1
2021-03-28 11:25:36.655 25778-25778/com.khumomashapa.notes D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@ab7bf2e[MainActivity]
2021-03-28 11:25:36.655 25778-25778/com.khumomashapa.notes D/InputMethodManager: getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2021-03-28 11:25:36.655 25778-25778/com.khumomashapa.notes V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=com.khumomashapa.notes ic=null mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
2021-03-28 11:25:36.656 25778-25778/com.khumomashapa.notes D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
2021-03-28 11:25:37.295 25778-25778/com.khumomashapa.notes I/ViewRootImpl@32ff46b[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
2021-03-28 11:25:37.334 25778-25778/com.khumomashapa.notes I/ViewRootImpl@32ff46b[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
2021-03-28 11:25:37.363 25778-25778/com.khumomashapa.notes D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-03-28 11:25:37.364 25778-25778/com.khumomashapa.notes E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.khumomashapa.notes, PID: 25778
    java.lang.NullPointerException: result_id must not be null
        at com.khumomashapa.notes.fragments.CalculatorFragment.onCreate(CalculatorFragment.kt:22)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2586)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:838)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1197)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:1080)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:119)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1866)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
2021-03-28 11:25:37.385 25778-25778/com.khumomashapa.notes I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 25778 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a fragment, `onCreate` gets called before your view is created. The lifecycle method you should be considering is `onViewCreated` which namely guarantees the view hierarchy has been created by this point.

---

You can take a look in more detail about the fragment lifecycle in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle#states).

Comment: Oh I understand. I'll give the onViewCreated method a go and see how it works out for me